# Idiomatic Column Aliasing

Tags: sql-server

What is more idiomatic in SQL Server world?

```
SELECT AliasName = expression
FROM TheTable
```

or

```
SELECT expression AS AliasName
FROM TheTable
```

Comment: Duplicate of [T-SQL - Aliasing using "=" versus "as"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1503295/t-sql-aliasing-using-versus-as). `AS` is more idiomatic in that it's ANSI-compliant. The rest is just opinion, and we already have a thread full of those.

Comment: Well I hoped I will get better answer than "I would use that, because I find it..." I was hoping for citation form MS why they introduced = or statement that = predates ANSI. I think that = was introduced later in hope to increase readability of complex expressions.

Answer (score 0):

I would answer by saying that you should probably generally use the second version, because it is ANSI compliant, and would run on most other databases with no modification.  I always have found the `alias = expression` syntax in SQL Server to be confusing, because I mistake it for an assignment of some sort, which is not really what is happening.

Comment: Gordon will also post shortly.  Let's see what he has to say.

Answer (score 0):

There does not seem to be industry wide preference, so this is opinion based.