# Show the name and the extension where the capital is an extension of name of the country from the table CITY

Tags: mysql, sql

For example, In 'Monaco-Ville' the name is Monaco and the extension is -Ville. This problem is from SQLZOO. I am having trouble making my solution look like the way the site requires.

```
SELECT name, REPLACE( capital, name, ' ')
FROM world
WHERE capital LIKE concat(name, '_%')
```

---

MY SOLUTION :

```
name        REPLACE( capi..
Andorra     la Vella
Guatemala   City
Kuwait      City
Mexico      City
Monaco      -Ville
Panama      City
```

---

what the answer should be...

```
name        ext
Andorra     la Vella
Guatemala   City
Kuwait      City
Mexico      City
Monaco      -Ville
Panama      City
```

Comment: Your answer looks correct to me.  If you want to rename the column, you need `as ext`.

Comment: Do you want to display an alias? In the case, you write "REPLACE( capital, name, ' ') as ext". Or your solution is not correct?

Comment: I'm not sure what's wrong. I tried  "REPLACE( capital, name, ' ') as ext". It changed the col name but it still shows that my ans is incorrect.

Comment: Is the output result of "MY SOLUTION" incorrect? In your query, If one space character is extra, the select expression is "REPLACE( capital, name, '')" not "REPLACE( capital, name, ' ')". If the extensions begin hyphen, the condition is "capital LIKE concat(name, '-%')" not "capital LIKE concat(name, '_%')". Note that underscore in the LIKE clause means any single character.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I rename a single column in a table at select?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/614238/how-can-i-rename-a-single-column-in-a-table-at-select)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an extra space between your two quotes: `' '`.

If you amend it to `SELECT name, REPLACE( capital, name, '')` it will give you the right answer; I am reviewing this same exercise at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this:

```
SELECT name, REPLACE( capital, name, '') as 'ext'
FROM world
WHERE capital LIKE concat(name, '_%')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT name, REPLACE(capital, name, '') AS ext
FROM world
WHERE capital LIKE CONCAT('%', name, '%')
AND LENGTH(capital) > LENGTH(name)
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer can be this:

```
SELECT name, REPLACE( capital, name, '')
FROM world
WHERE capital LIKE concat(name, '%_')
```

---

And I have meet some other question.

Sounds like that sqlzoo website has wrong setting for this question answer.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y8eyv.png)

when we click the "Submit SQL" button, the browser send a post request named 'sqlgo'.And there has our solution 'sql' and the sqlzoo offical answer 'answer'.The problem is that the sqlzoo offical answer doesn't work well.

```
select name,mid(capital,length(name)+1) ext
from world
where capital like concat(name,'_%')
```

So check the response for 'sqlgo',we can find the error information.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fKXYD.png)

Sqlzoo checks the difference between the result of our sql and the result of the answer sql. But now the answer sql doesn't work, so we can't get the correct answer.

we can modify the sql Engine to MySql from Microsoft SQL by the gear icon in the upper right corner. Then it could work well.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT REPLACE( capital, name, ' ') as ext
FROM world
WHERE capital like name + '%%' and capital not like name

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You should: a. explain what your answer is about, what it does. and b. use `code` blocks (place between \`\`\`Your code here\`\`\` charachters) to  format code as code.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT name, REPLACE(capital, name, '') AS ext  
FROM world
WHERE capital LIKE concat(name, '%')
AND capital <> name
```

1. If we don't add the last raw (AND capital <> name) to the code,  it will also list all the counties which have the same name with their capitals.

2. No need double side CONCAT('%', name, '%'). Instead, concat(name, '%') should be used. It asks for the extensions from the situations equal to this /capital/=/name+extension/

Comment: Code is a lot more helpful when it is accompanied by an explanation. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. This is particularly important when answering old questions (this one is two and a half years old) with existing answers. Please [edit] your answer and explain how it answers the specific question being asked, and how it differs from and improves upon what is already here. See [answer].